# How to find ridges by using Hessian matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, convolution, hessian-matrix

I want to find ridges for a given image. (Ridges not edges!)
An example is like the image below
[image]

I think Hessian matrix will work intuitively. So I hard coded Hessian matrix kernel by starting from a 2D-Gaussian equation as the links below described.
[How to build 2D hessian matrix kernel](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-ways-of-calculating-2-x-2-Hessian-matrix-for-2D-image-of-pixel-at-x-y-position)

I use `surf` to visualize the 3 second order derivative kernels (D_xx,D_yy and D_xy) I created and they look all correct. [image]

I then applied these kernels and did 2D convolution with my image.

I am not sure what to do next, should I need to represent eigen values and vectors by using D_xx,D_yy and D_xy? How can we pull out ridge lines from the image by using the eigen analysis of 2-by-2 matrix for each pixel?
Any idea, formula or even code will be much helpful.

Attached is the code to generate 2D Hessian matrix

```
[x y]=meshgrid(round(-N/2):round(N/2), round(-N/2):round(N/2));
common = x.^2+y.^2;
Lxx = ((-1+x.^2/(sigma^2)).*exp(-common/(2*sigma^2))) / (2*pi*sigma^4);
Lxx = Lxx./ sum(Lxx(:));

Lyy = ((-1+y.^2/(sigma^2)).*exp(-common/(2*sigma^2))) / (2*pi*sigma^4);
Lyy = Lyy./ sum(Lyy(:));

Lxy = ((x.*y)/(2*pi*sigma^6)).*exp(-common/(2*sigma^2));
Lxy = Lxy./ sum(Lxy(:));
```

Comment: Have you considered using threshold and sekleton?

Comment: @Steffen How did you use threshold for finding ridges? I do believe skeleton works for binary image processing but I am dealing with greyscale image.

Comment: Threshold to create a binary image where skeleton will work.

Comment: @Steffen Threshold method has its limitation. since we want to implement a auto scale selection method for finding ridges, it's too tricky to find a proper threshold for different dimensional feature images. I believe skeleton is the way for dealing with binary image, so I don't want to use it either.

Comment: @Steffen We are not simply dealing with the image shows above. We are dealing with multi-scale feature images by using different scales of DOG. What I show here is a large scale space image with lot of blur on it. Maybe it is ok to use threshold. But if you deal with the small scale space image, there will be a lot of noises and other staffs which may fail the threshold process.